# File upload in JSF 2.2

Tags: spring, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, spring-boot

My problem is that I cannot upload a file using JSF form. There is my component's code:

```
<h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:panelGrid>
        <h:inputText id="filenameInput"
                     value="#{uploadBean.filename}"
                     required="true"
                     requiredMessage="Filename is required"/>
        <p:message for="filenameInput"/>
        <h:inputFile id="fileInput"
                     label="inputFile"
                     value="#{uploadBean.file}"
                     validator="#{uploadBean.validateFile}"/>
        <p:message for="fileInput"/>
        <h:commandButton id="submitBtn"
                         value="Upload file"
                         actionListener="#{uploadBean.uploadFile()}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="uploadForm"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Implementation of uploadBean:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@Component
@Scope("view")
public class UploadBean {

private Part file;
private String filename;

public void uploadFile() throws IOException {
    if (file != null && filename != null && !filename .isEmpty()) {
        // Some processing
    }
}
```

Just to point exact versions of libraries that I am using, see some gradle imports below:

```
compile group: 'org.omnifaces', name: 'omnifaces', version: '1.7'
compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-api', version: '2.2.6'
compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-impl', version: '2.2.6'
compile group: 'org.primefaces', name: 'primefaces', version: '5.3'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
```

If enctype is removed from h:form (along with h:inputFile and p:message for it), form is submitted, validation on remaining field works and everything seems to be fine. But I need that file, obviously.

If nothing is changed and code version visible above is used, then I can see some actions in server logs, but page is not reloaded, nothing really happens in the browser (even in console). If I click button second time without reloading page, then absolutly nothing happens.

Another interesting thing is that it works on production server, but not on development and locally. The only difference that I know is that production is using external Tomcat instance, but development and local application works on Spring's embedded Tomcat. Unfortunatelly, this is an legacy code and I don't know anything more about production- whole development team was exchanged and I don't have direct access there (which sucks).

Comment: Could you provide the implementation for your `uploadBean`? That way anyone can try your code. You also miss the spring boot parent dependency.

Comment: I see that you're using PrimeFaces. If you have configured its `FileUploadFilter`, then JSF 2.2 native file upload may not work. At least, the described problem is not reproducible when creating a scratchpad project based on the information provided so far and with the remainder set to bare/sane defaults.

Comment: Added implementation of uploadBean. I cannot see any implemented filter and double checked for FileUploadFilter. There were no findings.

Comment: OK, then most likely Spring or Spring Boot plays a key role in the problem (I did not use it when trying to reproduce your problem; I just use stock Java EE).